# How can I give a number to a symbolic variable in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I try to declare a symbolic variable in MATLAB with this code:

```
 syms a;
```

I do my computation on this variable and all thing is fine. But my problem is that, I don't know how can I give a number to variable and get the result as a number. For example the answer of my code is

```
   answer=exp(-10*a);
```

For instance I want to give 40 to "a" and get the answer as

```
   answer = 
        1.9152e-174
```

I really appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use [eval](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/mupad/stdlib/eval.html)

```
syms a;
answer = exp(-10*a);

a=40;
eval(answer)

ans =
  1.9152e-174
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [SUBS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/subs.html) function from the Symbolic Math Toolbox to perform symbolic substitution.

```
syms a;
answer = exp(-10*a);

subs(answer,a,40)


ans =

  1.9152e-174
```